# MS Access VBA subscript out of range error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to send two values as an OpenArgs property in Open event of an Access form.

```
  Me.str1 & ";" & Me.str2
```

In the Open event of the form I am doing:

```
Dim strArgs() As String

    If Trim(Nz(Me.OpenArgs, "")) = "" Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
        strArgs() = Split(Me.OpenArgs, ";")

    Me.str1 = strArgs(0)

    Me.str2 = strArgs(1)
```

I get the

> Subscript Out Of Range

error on `Me.str2=strArgs(1)` line

I have tried `Dim strArgs(2) as String` to declare the array length but that did not help either.

Comment: Apparently, Me.OpenArgs does not have what you expect.

Comment: @zhekaus (and June) are right. Your code, as is, can't fail for the expected input. Thus, the input (OpenArgs) is not as expected.

Comment: Edit question to show complete line of code attempting to pass OpenArgs. Assume using OpenForm method. Are you sure using the correct argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is not necessary to parse only 2 elements from OpenArgs.

```
Me.str1 = Left(Me.OpenArgs, InStr(Me.OpenArgs, ";") - 1)

Me.str2 = Mid(Me.OpenArgs, InStr(Me.OpenArgs, ";") + 1)
```